# Performance Testing Acrobat Reader(Standalone)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to run a performance test of an acrobat reader(PDF). The pdf load's an authorization page and need to capture that to sign in to load the PDF content. Need some thoughts on how to capture this using Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Load testing Acrobat Reader per se doesn't make a lot of sense (as long as you are not an Adobe employee).

If you need to simulate hundreds/thousands of Reader instances opening the authorization page it's sufficient to simulate the network footprint.

If the protocol is [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) you can even record the traffic using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). It respects [operating system proxy settings](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-proxy/td-p/9607938) so you need to

1. Set your OS to use localhost as the proxy host and 8888 as the proxy port
2. Import JMeter's self-signed certificate into [Trusted Root Certification Authorities store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store)
3. Perform the actions in the Acrobat Reader

JMeter should capture the associated network requests and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

See [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article for more information.

If protocol is not HTTP(S) - basically the same approach: capture the traffic using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), identify the protocol, choose the relevant [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and configure it to send exactly the same request(s) as Acrobat Reader does